# How to use only max/average pooling layer in Tensorflow for 1D array?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a .wav file which I read into an array in python.

```
import wave as wav
path = "Casio-Celesta-C5.wav"
f = wav.open(path)
data_sound = f.readframes(-1)
data_sound = np.frombuffer(data_sound,"Int16")
```

I want to perform average/max pooling on it with Tensorflow or Keras. But I'm not familiar with this framework so can anyone show me how to implement it? Or do anyone know another way to do it without Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Install Tensorflow

pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-rc1

Maxpooling - `tf.nn.max_pool1d`

Avgpooling - `tf.nn.avg_pool1d`

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/max_pool1d
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MaxPool1D

#### Input data

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randn(4).astype('float32')
print(a)
bac = a[None][:,:,None] # convert to batch/features/channels format
# here batch size = 1, no. of channels = 1
```

[0.02703167 0.382881   0.57891446 0.58068216]

#### Tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
output = tf.nn.max_pool1d(bac, 2, 2, padding='VALID')
print(np.squeeze(output)) #strip off the additional dimensions
```

[0.382881   0.58068216]

#### Keras

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
output = layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, strides=2)(bac)
print(np.squeeze(output)) #strip off the additional dimensions
```

[0.382881   0.58068216]

Comment: Thank for the answer. If i use RGB image as input,should I use MaxPool2D or MaxPool3D?

Comment: In Neural Networks, MaxPool2D is used - it's a 2D image with 3 channels.